# Auto Repeat a MediaElement

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm trying to auto repeat a `MediaElement`. I did that using the following code:

```
    <MediaElement Name="MainMedia" MediaEnded="MainMedia_MediaEnded_1" />

    private void MainMedia_MediaEnded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainMedia.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
        MainMedia.Play();
    }
```

But I was wondering if there is any better solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a property called `IsLooping`. If you set that to `true` it will auto repeat the media.